# How to get localized version of built-in windows 'Network Service' account?

Tags: c#, windows, iis-6

In order to setup my web application I need to give a full control to a certain folder for a `'NETWORK SERVICE'` account. It works fine, but on a non English systems I'm getting `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException` . This is because the name of this built-in account is localized for that system (I'm using harcoded value `'NETWORK SERVICE'`).
Is there a way to find out programmatically what the localized version of `'NETWORK SERVICE'` is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
var account = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can p/invoke [LookupAccountSid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166.aspx), since it returns [the localized account name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272.aspx). The SID of `Network Service` is `S-1-5-20`.

You can find the method signature and an invocation example [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LookupAccountSid.html).